# Shell - Pass env variable to Python Script

Tags: python, shell

I have the shell script where I create a Python file on the fly:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")

GIT_PASSWORD=${args[0]}
export $GIT_PASSWORD

python - << EOF

import os

print(os.environ.get("GIT_PASSWORD"))
                                                         
EOF

echo $GIT_PASSWORD

echo "Back to bash"
```

I want to be able to access the variable `GIT_PASSWORD`, but unfortunately, I am not able to pass it to the python file.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I may fix that?

Comment: `export $GIT_PASSWORD` If the password is ABC, then this becomes `export ABC`

Comment: `export GIT_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that you're not actually setting an env variable, you need to change the export:

```bash
export GIT_PASSWORD=$GIT_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts 1: flag
do
        case "${flag}" in
                1) GIT_PASS=${OPTARG};;
        esac
done

export GIT_PASSWORD=$GIT_PASS

python - << EOF

import os

print(os.environ.get("GIT_PASSWORD"))
                                                         
EOF

echo $GIT_PASSWORD

echo "Back to bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason to use an environment variable at all; a simply command line argument would suffice.

```
GIT_PASSWORD=$1

python - "$GIT_PASSWORD" << EOF 
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])                                               
EOF

echo "Back to bash"
```